# Simple binomial probability question

Tags: calculus, probability

I have been trying to equate the two with no avail please help.I have been using the binomial distribution equation.

Var x has binomial distribution n=3 and p=2/3
Var y has binomial distribution n2 = 4 and p2= 1/2

Var x and y are independent

Probability that P(X=Y) ?

Comment: Please see the [introduction to posting mathematical expressions](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $X$ and $Y$ are independent, then $P(X,Y)=P(X)P(Y)$. You can calculate the probabilities for the 4 cases of interest (both X and Y are equal to 0, 1, 2, 3) and add up the probabilities of the four cases, since the four cases are exclusive. That is,
$$P(X=Y)=P(0,0)+P(1,1)+P(2,2)+P(3,3)$$